# can I build a css class on the fly in tiny mce?

Tags: tinymce

I'm using tiny mce, but I found it adds multiple spans with inline styles to the content for any applied style. Inline styles are not W3c Compliant, so must avoid inline css. Is it possible to create css class on the fly and apply to the selection, while editing content in tiny mce ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible, but it took me some effort. What needs to be done is to write the class into the head of the editors iframe. Here is some example code which should work for IE,FF, Safari and point you into the right direction:

```
fonturl = "http://myfonts.com/arial.ttf"
csstext_to_add = '@font-face {font-family: "ownfont";src: url("'+fonturl+'");}'; // example
iframe_id = ed.id;
with(document.getElementById(iframe_id).contentWindow){
  var h=document.getElementsByTagName("head");
  if (!h.length) {
    return;
  }
  var newStyleSheet=document.createElement("style");
  newStyleSheet.type="text/css";
  h[0].appendChild(newStyleSheet);
  try{
    if (typeof newStyleSheet.styleSheet !== "undefined") {
      newStyleSheet.styleSheet.cssText = csstext_to_add;
    }
    else {
      newStyleSheet.appendChild(document.createTextNode(csstext_to_add));
      newStyleSheet.innerHTML=csstext_to_add;
    }
  }
  catch(e){}
}
```

It is also possible to add that class as option into a dropdown (what takes some effort).

Answer (score 1):

Thariama's answer was perfect. I'm using the tinyMCE jQuery connector for some of my pages and I have multiple instances of tinyMCE on the page. I made some modifications, but essentially its the same thing. I've created a text area field on the page that people can provide their own CSS. Also, I needed to change some CSS rules on the fly...

```
// function to change tinyMCE css on the fly
function checkCustomCSS() {
   var $css = $('#page_css'),
      newcss;
   if ($css.val().length > 0) {
      // since front end, we are wrapping their HTML in a wrapper and
      // the tinyMCE edit iFrame is just using <body>, we need to change
      // some rules so they can see the changes
      newcss = $css.val().replace('#content_wrapper', 'body');
      // loop through each tinyMCE editor and apply the code changes
      // You could check the editor.id to make sure that the correct
      // editor gets the appropriate changes.
      $.each(tinyMCE.editors, function() {
         var $this = $(this),
             editorID = $this[0].id,
             $ifrm = $('#' + editorID+ '_ifr'),
             cwin, head, sheet;
         if ($ifrm.length > 0 /* && editorID === 'OUR_EDITOR_ID_NAME' */) {
             cwin = $ifrm[0].contentWindow;
             head = cwin.document.getElementsByTagName("head");
             if (!head.length) {
                return;
             }
             sheet = cwin.document.createElement("style");
             sheet.type = "text/css";
             head[0].appendChild(sheet);
             try {
                 if (typeof sheet.styleSheet !== "undefined") {
                    sheet.styleSheet.cssText = newcss;
                 } else {
                    sheet.appendChild(cwin.document.createTextNode(newcss));
                    sheet.innerHTML = newcss;
                 }
             } catch (e) {}
         }
     });
  }
}
```

Then in the tinyMCE init call I added and onInit call to setup changes to the #page_css , like this:

```
oninit: function() {
   $('#page_css').on('change', function() {
      checkCustomCSS();
   });
}
```

Works like a charm.